# Inequality of distribution functions multivariate and univariate.

Tags: statistics

I need help with the solution of this exercise.
We consider that $F$ is the multivariate distribution funcction of a random vector $X\in\mathbb{R}^p$, and $F_i$ is the univariate distribution of this $i-th$ component $X_i$

Show that  $$max\{1-p+\sum_{i=0}^{p}F_i(r_i),0\}\leq F(r)\leq \min_{i=1,...,p}F_i(r_i)$$
For any $r\in \mathbb{R}^p$

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: What have you tried? For example the second $\le$ is not difficult, and then considering $-X$ might help with the first $\le$

Comment: How you can see that the rhs is not difficult? I don´t understand what argument can I use.

Comment: $F(r) = P(X_1 \le r_1 \cap X_2 \le r_2 \cap \cdots) \le P(X_i \le r_i) =F_i(r_i)\, \forall i$ and so for the minimum of them

Comment: Cool, I have never have seen this definition, what about this:  $P(x_1\leq r_1,X_2\leq r_2,...X_p\leq r_p)\leq P(X_i\leq r_i)$? Why this part how to see this property?  Could you explain me in more detail? I don´t understand why the inequality holds.

Comment: Maybe is something like $P(A\cap B)\leq P(A)$?

Comment: Yes, like that.

Comment: but I can't justify that because I know by definition that $P(A\cap B)=P(A)+P(B)-P(A\cup B)$ then since i dont have information about the independence ot the events, $P(A\cup B)\leq P(A)+P(B)$ how to quit the P(B)??

Comment: $P(A\cap B) + P(A \cap B^c) = P(A)$ as the sum of probabilities of mutually exclusive events and  $P(A \cap B^c) \ge 0$ as a probability

Comment: Then how to use the suggestion $-X$ could you explain me? I have been thinking how to solve this, but I can't

Comment: First, I am confused, if the distribution of a random vector $X$ is $F$, the distribution of $-X$ is $-F$? How to prove that?, then how to find the relation between your suggestion and $1-p+\sum_{i=1}^pF_i(r_i)$ I am not very clear with it. $$1-p+P(X_2\leq r_2)+.....+P(X_p\leq r_p)\leq F(r)$$ how to conclude that?? I am very confused. Maybe this is very basic but I am a little bit lost.

Comment: $P(-X \le -x) = P(X \ge x) \ge P(X \gt x) = 1- P(X \le x) = 1-F(x)$ and for a continuous random variable you have equality